# Trouble passing the correct information from a tableview to a new view controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Right now I have a program that displays different organizations in a tableview. When an organization is selected, then it displays a screen that passes the name of that specific organization. However, the problem is that when I click on "organization 2" of "section 1" I get the results that would be displayed in "organization 1" of "section 1". How would I fix this so that, when I click "organization 2" of "section 1" it displays the correct information?

Here is my code for the first view controller.

```
import UIKit

struct Organizations {
var sectionTitle = String()
var rowTitles = [String]()
}

class SearchOrganizationsViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var searchOrganizations: Organizations?
var selectedRow = 0
var organizations = [Organizations(sectionTitle: "section 1", rowTitles: ["organization 1", "organization 2", "organization 3"]),
Organizations(sectionTitle: "section 2", rowTitles: ["organization 1", "organization 2"]),
Organizations(sectionTitle: "section 3", rowTitles: ["organization 1"])
]

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
}

extension SearchOrganizationsViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "searchCell")
cell?.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
cell?.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 3
if searching {
cell?.textLabel?.text = self.searchArray[indexPath.section].rowTitles[indexPath.row]
} else {
cell?.textLabel?.text = self.organizations[indexPath.section].rowTitles[indexPath.row]
}
return cell!
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
selectedOrganizations = organizations[indexPath.section]
performSegue(withIdentifier: "organizationDetailSegue", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
if let destination = segue.destination as?    OrganizationsDetailViewController {
     destination.organization = selectedOrganizations
     destination.selectedRow = selectedRow 
 }
 }
```

Here is my code for the second view controller.

```
import UIKit

class OrganizationsDetailViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var organizationNameLabel: UILabel!

var organization: Organizations? = nil 
var selecterRow: Int = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
setupLabel()
}

private func setupLabel() {
    guard let org = self.organization else { return }
    self.organizationNameLabel.text = org.rowTitles[selectedRow]
}
}
```

Comment: You should add your `numberOfRowsInSection` and `numberOfSections` method in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your `didSelectRow` to this to fix your mentioned issue:

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedOrganizations = searching ? searchArray[indexPath.section] : organizations[indexPath.section]
    selectedRow = indexPath.row
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "organizationDetailSegue", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I still have the same error. It doesn't display the unique value for "organization 2".

Comment: Add your `numberOfRowsInSection` and `numberOfSections` method in your code.

Comment: @Frankenstein happy copying =D

Comment: @Sh_Khan Sorry mate, turns out I noticed these changes but was a bit late to update my answer. You can see that's exactly the reason why I asked him to add the other methods for dataSource.